# Degree sequence in $O(n)$

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, recreational-mathematics

How can we determine the whether a sequence of non negative integers is a valid degree sequence in $O(n)$. I have determined an $O(n\log n)$ algorithm using erdos-gallai theorem.

Comment: Is the input sorted?

Comment: No the input is not sorted.

Comment: So your $O(n\log n)$ algorithm is, sort the input and then check that the condition for the E-G theorem holds?

Comment: "check that the condition for the E-G theorem holds" should also be done in O(nlogn) . I have figured out a way of implementing that in O(nlogn) which is an improvement over the trivial way to do this second part in O(n^2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort $n$ numbers that are between $0$ and $n$ in $O(n)$ time and $O(n)$ space using a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). $O(n\log n)$ sorting is only required when the numbers might be large.

This paper of  Zoltán Király "[Recognizing graphic degree sequences and generating all realizations](http://www.cs.elte.hu/egres/tr/egres-11-11.ps)" provides an implementation of the [Havel-Hakimi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28graph_theory%29#Degree_sequence) which is claimed to run in $O(n\log \log n)$ time, and a new algorithm which is claimed to run in $O(n)$ time.