# Is there software to reconstruct a graph from its degree sequence?

Tags: graph-theory

I use Mathematica but it does not have a function to reconstruct a graph from its degree sequence. eg : (5,1,1,1,1,1).

Is there a software that does this?

Comment: What would you expect this software to do when the graph sequence does not uniquely determine a graph?

Comment: There can be multiple non-isomorphic graphs with the same degree sequence, e.g. $(2,2,2,2,2,2)$ can be two triangles or it could be a $6$-cycle.  What... do you expect it to be able to graph all such possible graphs up to isomorphism for a given degree sequence?  Do you have any idea how hard that would be for long enough sequences?

Comment: As an aside, graphing the graph with $(5,1,1,1,1,1)$ should be easy... it is a [star graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)), made obvious by the fact there are six vertices, one of which is degree five and all others are degree one.  Once you've drawn the degree five vertex there is nothing else to do in the drawing of the graph.

Comment: @JMoravitz There is an algorithm for doing this http://math.stackexchange.com/a/712297/26904 although sadly for me it generates isomorphic solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not simple, in general. There are $19$ different graphs represented by the degree sequence $(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)$ (cubic graphs with $10$ nodes), [shown here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_simple_cubic_graphs#10_vertices).

You might be interested in [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2152845/206402) I got to [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2145024/206402) on graphs with the degree sequence $(5,4,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)$, which represents a tree, but still had - as it turns out - $150$ different options. [The answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2152845/206402) describes the software used.

Some degree sequences are easy, of course. As others have noted your example is just a star:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

An integer sequence $(n_1,\ldots,n_k)$ is called *realizable* if there is a graph $G = (V,E)$ with vertex set $V = \{ v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ such that such $deg(v_i) = n_i$ for all $ i \in [1,n]$.

However, there can be more than one graph with a given degree sequence, and conversely there are integer sequences that do not correspond to the degree sequence of any graph.

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DegreeSequence.html for a short overview of results.

[In 1962 Hakimi showed that there is a polynomial-time algorithm for checking if an integer sequence is realizable.](http://compalg.inf.elte.hu/~tony/Oktatas/Algoritmusok-hatekonysaga/Hakimi-SIAM62.pdf) The same result was actually established already in 1955 by Havel, but unfortunately the paper was only published in Czech.

Later it has been shown that some other problems concerning degree sequences are in fact NP-complete.
See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.00730.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to someone who has answered something similar. If you can code, this is useful.
[Constructing a graph from a degree sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527530/constructing-a-graph-from-a-degree-sequence)